# Water has quit running thru my humidifier.

Tags: furnace, humidifier

Furnace humidifier dry as a bone.  have changed the filter, duh, that is the only thing I know how to do! Bottom line, there is no water running through it.

Answer (score 1):

## Novice

### Check the humidity

The humidifier should only turn on if the humidity is below a set level.  Make sure the humidity is actually below this level.

### Clean the inlet

Check the inlet (where the water comes in), and make sure it's not all gunked up.

### Check the valve

If the humidifier supply line connects to the water supply via a [saddle valve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_valve), close and reopen the valve (and consider replacing the valve, which will require shutting off the water since the valve pokes a hole in the pipe).

### Set the humidistat

If a [humidistat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humidistat) is used, make sure it's set properly.

## Intermediate

### Check for water at the solenoid

Close the valve supplying the humidifier, and remove the supply tube from the supply side of the solenoid. Open the valve just a bit, and make sure water is coming from the tube.

***TIP:** Wrap a rag/towel around the open end of the hose, and hold it tight when opening the valve.  The rag/towel will prevent the water from spraying out the end of the tube. Also, don't forget to hold the rag/towel wrapped tube over a bucket.*

### Check for power at the humidistat

Open up the humidistat, and use a multimeter/voltmeter to make sure the humidistat has power (most likely 24 volts).

***NOTE:** Depending on the installation, the humidistat may only have power when the furnace is running.*

### Check for power at the solenoid

With the humidistat open, and the furnace running. Set the humidistat to the highest setting, and check to see if you have voltage going to the solenoid.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to expand on the point above about closing and reopening the saddle valve. (see "Check the valve")

Your saddle valve may be clogged with fine particles that have settled in the pipe, especially so if the valve has been installed on the bottom of the pipe.
You can try to clear the clog by FULLY closing the valve and reopening it. You might encounter some resistance as the pin is driven through the clog and back into the pipe, be sure to close the valve FULLY.
Good Luck.